# PHP: How to make a good interface to create articles?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I would like to create an interface in my website with HTML and CSS so that the admin can make articles to be shown on the home page. But I don't how I could make the paragraphs and break-rows to seem correctly without being together.

What functions should I use or create to make a good validation?

I'm going to send the information from this interface to a database. From the database, I'll retrieve the information and show it on the home page.

Besides, do you have any suggestions to give me?

Comment: Are you asking for a [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) recommendation, or how to build your own? Please clarify your question.

Comment: If you are new to PHP and WEb Development try CMS(Content mangement systems) like Droopal, MAgento, Joomla etc where you can get templates of your requirements

Comment: I'm trying to create by myself an interface.

Comment: You could use CMSs like @TusharGupta mentioned. If you want to do it on your own, we have to know what you are able to code (do you know PHP, MySQL, HTML, CSS?) If you want to code that, you have to make a plan how the articles will look like at the end and what for inputs you need, e.g. heading, subheading, time, content, sign of creator... then you can create a database and then you can start creating the backend (so the interface for the admin) and at the end the frontend (so the function to show the articles on your site).

Comment: I'm going to validate the data at the PHP language. The database is ready and is being managed by MYSQL. I have knowledge in these 4 languages you have cited. My problem is to make a good validation and a good showing. The article will have title and body.

Comment: Try Bootstrap ... It will help you in both UI and validations and very easy to use

Comment: Ok, with validation I can help you. What do you mean with `a good showing`? The styling? - do you have a link to your website so we can imagine how it should look like?

Comment: I am already using bootstrap to make the layout. My problem is in PHP.

Comment: Then add your code you have tried ...

Comment: So what do you want to validate? Do you want to have a specific length of the title / body or something like that?

Comment: Good showing = As explained above, I want to make the paragraphs and the break-rows to seem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not gonna lie; if you're new to PHP, building your own content management system will be difficult.

Learning is always a worthy goal. I suggest familiarizing yourself with the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/docs.php).

**Start small.** Build just the admin page first and see what you're in for. You'll probably want a [rich text editor](https://www.bing.com/search?q=html%20rich%20text%20editor), username and password for the admin ([NB - How to verify passwords properly!](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)), etc.

- For the line breaks and styling? Format paragraph elements using CSS.
- For the interactive HTML and validation, if you are already familiar with HTML and the Javascript DOM, I would suggest learning to use a data binding library- [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) or something similar. That will simplify your HTML interactions dramatically. If you are just a beginner, learn how to [manipulate the page using Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).
- I'm assuming you are familiar with databases in general? PHP works well with MySQL.
  Search for what do you don't know. This isn't a tutorial site, but [it isn't hard to find](https://www.bing.com/search?q=php%20mysql%20tutorial) a tutorial to fill you in with exactly what you need.

On your journey, **remember, [search is your friend](https://www.bing.com/search?q=how%20to%20build%20cms%20php).**

Comment: OP haven't asked to build his own cms.

Comment: An interface for an admin to write content, store it and display it = a content management system. Not full featured, obviously.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using something difficult like AngularJS (at the beginning) for a simple backend. Because validation is the weak point in AngularJS...

Comment: I've liked it. What would you recommend? I'll add others.

Comment: I like it, too, but for beginners it's quite hard, isn't it? For this needs a simple formular with a bit of jQuery / Javascript is enough I guess.